# How to tell the difference between SD and HD movies on netflix api without quality property

Tags: netflix

Previously in the Netflix API when you requested `format_availability` for a movie in the catalog, if it was available to stream there would be an `instant` section. Under that, there would be a property `"quality": "HD"` for HD movies available in 720p. It would be omitted if the movie was only available in SD/480p.

It seems on the October 16th, 2013 that the `quality` property has been removed from the API.
Comparing API responses for HD and SD movie on the Netflix site I can't really see any indication of a format difference. There is a new property since I last examined this code `is_superhd_available` but I think that is to show the difference between 720p and 1080p. This might be a bug as, I've seen the API do some odd things in the past then revert to normal function, or maybe there is a new property coming. I would appreciate some feedback.

Answer (score 0):

It appears it was a bug in the service the quality flag ended up coming back.